# Read random line from .txt file

Tags: c, file, random

I'm trying to upgrade my Hangman game by reading random words from a .txt file. Thing is, I can't figure out how to read a random line from the .txt file. There are single words on every new line of the .txt file.

```
void ler_palavras()
{
    FILE *words;

    if ((words = fopen("words.txt", "r")) == NULL) {
        printf("Error! opening file");
        exit(1);
    }

    // reads text until newline
    fscanf(words,"%[^\n]", word);
    fclose(words);
}
```

Comment: first read ALL words then pick one using rand() on the range (0,nb words).

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre ill try that, thanks for the reply

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: `rand` will only produce in range (0, `RAND_MAX`), and `RAND_MAX` is often just 32767, so a words file of any size would require multiple calls to `rand` with the results shifted and `|`-ed together. Or use a better, if less portable, PRNG library that can give you more scalable randomness.

Comment: @ShadowRanger you're right. Did not think of that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If, for some reason, you can't just load the whole set of lines into memory (too big or whatever), there is a way to select a random entry from a streaming set of entries. It won't scale indefinitely, and it will exhibit small biases, but this is a game, not cryptography, so that shouldn't be a dealbreaker.

The logic is:

1. Declare a buffer to hold the word
2. Open the file
3. For each line:

   - Increment a counter indicating which line you're on
   - Generate a random `double` (e.g. with [`drand48`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/drand48) or whatever PRNG facilities are available to you)
   - If `1.0 / lineno > randval`, replace the currently stored word with the word from the current line (so the first line is auto stored, the second line is 50% likely to replace it, the third is 33% likely to do so, etc.)
4. When you run out of lines, whatever is stored in `word` is your selection

Assuming the number of lines is small enough (and the range of `double`s produced by your PRNG is fine-grained enough), this gives as close as possible to an equal likelihood of any given line being selected; for two lines, each has a 50/50 shot, for three, 33.33...%, etc.

I lack a C compiler right now, but the basic code would look like:

```
/* Returns a random line (w/o newline) from the file provided */
char* choose_random_word(const char *filename) {
    FILE *f;
    size_t lineno = 0;
    size_t selectlen;
    char selected[256]; /* Arbitrary, make it whatever size makes sense */
    char current[256];
    selected[0] = '\0'; /* Don't crash if file is empty */

    f = fopen(filename, "r"); /* Add your own error checking */
    while (fgets(current, sizeof(current), f)) {
        if (drand48() < 1.0 / ++lineno) {
            strcpy(selected, current);
        }
    }
    fclose(f);
    selectlen = strlen(selected);
    if (selectlen > 0 && selected[selectlen-1] == '\n') {
        selected[selectlen-1] = '\0';
    }
    return strdup(selected);
}
```

Comment: Upvoted for ingenuity, but a game of hangman with a billion words to choose from would be quite challenging, I think :-)

Comment: @squeamishossifrage: True. But in the case of Hangman, where a word is only being selected once per game, storing the whole words file in memory is wasteful, and the cost of iterating the file once per _game_ based on user input is likely unnoticeable (if it's a problem, grab the next word in a background thread while the game runs ;-) ). It makes sense both for huge files or cases where reading from the file is infrequent enough to not justify slurping the whole thing into memory.

Comment: Alternative: throw a dice; seek to the position relative to the file size; read until next `\n`; read word.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie: True, but that introduces bias; you're more likely to select a word following a long word than a word following short word.

Comment: @ShadowRanger I think that just might work. Big thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`rand()` has its limitations including only generating values `0` to `RAND_MAX` and a file can have many times `RAND_MAX` lines.  Assuming the line count is on the order of `RAND_MAX/10` or less, the following will meet OP's goals.

Perform one pass to count the number of lines. --> `lc`

For each random line needed, re-read the file's lines, from beginning up the line index *before* some random number in the `[0... lc-1]` range.

Then simply read and print that line.  No need for a line buffer.  The file is the line buffer.  The code re-uses `Line_Count()` for both the total line count calculation and for reading until the nth line.

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

// Return line count, but stop once the count exceeds a maximum
int Line_Count(FILE *istream, int line_index) {
  int lc = 0;
  int previous = '\n';
  int ch;
  rewind(istream);
  while (line_index > 0 && (ch = fgetc(istream)) != EOF) {
    if (ch == '\n') {
      line_index--;
    }
    if (previous == '\n') {
      lc++;
    }
    previous = ch;
  }
  return lc;
}

void print_random_line(FILE *istream, int line_index) {
  printf("%8d: <", line_index + 1);
  Line_Count(istream, line_index);
  int ch;
  while ((ch = fgetc(istream)) != EOF && ch != '\n') {
    if (isprint(ch)) {
      putchar(ch);
    }
  }
  printf(">\n");
}

int main() {
  srand((unsigned) time(NULL));
  FILE *istream = fopen("test.txt", "r");
  assert(istream);
  int lc = Line_Count(istream, RAND_MAX);
  assert(lc && lc < RAND_MAX);
  for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    print_random_line(istream, rand() % lc);
  }
  fclose(istream);
}
```

Comment: `rand`'s range is 0 to `RAND_MAX`, not `INT_MAX`. The former is often more restrictive, on many systems, it's just 32767, which is significantly smaller than the number of lines in a reasonably sized words file. You'd definitely want to mix together multiple outputs of `rand` on such a system.

Comment: @ShadowRanger Yes of course, should have written `RAND_MAX` rather than `INT_MAX`.  I did code with that in mind. Aside from DOS systems do your have in mind a current platform that has a file system and `RAND_MAX == 32767`?

Comment: @chux [32767 is still the current value in Windows](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2dfe3bzd.aspx). Everywhere else it's `0x7fffffff`.

Comment: @squeamishossifrage LSNED!   Detail "32767 is still the current value in **Visual Studio**."  It is 2147483647 with my gcc compiler - in Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution, still limited by `RAND_MAX`, that doesn't require reading each line up to the chosen line. The idea is to use a binary file that stores each word in the same number of bytes, so any word can be accessed by using `fseek()` and `fread()`. The first entry in the file is a `long` value that stores the number of words in the file. When words are added, this value is updated.

Here is an implementation that looks for an ordinary text file called `wordlist.txt`, which has one word on each line. If found, the program updates (or creates, if necessary) a file called `wordlist.fmt`. The update function reads in each word from the text file, skipping blank lines, and stores it in the binary file in a fixed number of bytes. After reading in all of the words, the word count is updated. After running the program once with a text file, you should remove the text file, or the next run will add the words again. The `.fmt` file should stay, and if you want to add more words, just put a new text file in the directory with the executable and run it again.

The loop that prints five random words generates a random number, uses that number to move to a file position containing a word, reads that word into an array, and prints it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#define RAW_WORDS  "wordlist.txt"
#define FMT_WORDS  "wordlist.fmt"
#define OFFSET_SZ  (sizeof(long))
#define MAXWORD    30

void update_words(FILE *fp_fmt, FILE *fp_raw);
void strip(char *str);

int main(void)
{
    FILE *raw_words, *formatted_words;
    char word[MAXWORD];
    long wordcount;
    int i;
    int wpos;

    raw_words = fopen(RAW_WORDS, "r");

    /* Try to open existing file for update, otherwise open new file */ 
    if ((formatted_words = fopen(FMT_WORDS, "r+b")) == NULL){
        if ((formatted_words = fopen(FMT_WORDS, "w+b")) == NULL) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Unable to open file %s\n", FMT_WORDS);
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        } else {                    // initialize file wordcount
            wordcount = 0L;
            fwrite(&wordcount, OFFSET_SZ, 1, formatted_words);
            fflush(formatted_words);
        }
    }

    /* Update FMT_WORDS file if RAW_WORDS is present */
    if (raw_words != NULL)
        update_words(formatted_words, raw_words);

    /* Get 5 random words and print them */
    srand((unsigned)time(NULL));

    rewind(formatted_words);
    fread(&wordcount, OFFSET_SZ, 1, formatted_words);

    printf("Five random words from %s:\n", FMT_WORDS);
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        wpos = rand() % wordcount;
        fseek(formatted_words, wpos * MAXWORD + OFFSET_SZ, SEEK_SET);
        fread(word, MAXWORD, 1, formatted_words);
        puts(word);
    }

    if (raw_words && (fclose(raw_words) != 0))
        fprintf(stderr, "Unable to close file %s\n", RAW_WORDS);
    if (fclose(formatted_words) != 0)
        fprintf(stderr, "Unable to close file %s\n", FMT_WORDS);

    return 0;
}

void update_words(FILE *fp_fmt, FILE *fp_raw)
{
    char word[MAXWORD];
    long wordcount;

    /* Read in wordcount and move to end of file */
    rewind(fp_fmt);
    fread(&wordcount, OFFSET_SZ, 1, fp_fmt);
    fseek(fp_fmt, wordcount * MAXWORD, SEEK_CUR);

    /* Write formatted words, skipping blank lines */
    while (fgets(word, MAXWORD, fp_raw) != NULL) {
        if (word[0] != '\n') {
            strip(word);
            if (fwrite(word, MAXWORD, 1, fp_fmt) != 1) {
                fprintf(stderr, "Error writing to %s\n", FMT_WORDS);
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
            ++wordcount;
        }
    }

    /* Update wordcount in file and flush output */
    rewind(fp_fmt);
    fwrite(&wordcount, OFFSET_SZ, 1, fp_fmt);
    fflush(fp_fmt);
}

void strip(char *str)
{
    while (*str != '\n' && *str != '\0')
        str++;
    *str = '\0';
}
```