# How can I read in a random string from a large list of words in C?

Tags: c, file, io, scanf, stdio

I'm developing a basic implementation of the game hangman.

I have a text file of the most 1000 common English language words and I'd like to just choose one of those at random to be the word in my game.

I know I need to use fopen and fscanf to get the word into a string in my program, but how do I choose which string to read in?

Would I have to import the whole list into an array and then choose one from there? Or is there a way I can just select which word to scan in?

Comment: have you tried using the rand() function to generate a number between 1 and 1000 ?

Comment: See this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40118509/read-random-line-from-txt-file).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You ***don't*** need to read all the words into your program just to select one.

You can instead seek to a random point in the word file, creep along until your see a newline (or whatever separates words), use `fgets()` or `scanf()` to read in one word and close the file:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>

void random_word(const char *file_name, char *buffer, size_t length) {

    FILE *file = fopen(file_name, "r");

    if (file == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Can't open %s!\n", file_name);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    (void) fseek(file, 0L, SEEK_END);
    long size = ftell(file);

    int c = EOF;

    while (c == EOF || fgets(buffer, length, file) == NULL) {
        long offset = random() % size;

        (void) fseek(file, offset, SEEK_SET);

        while ((c = getc(file)) != EOF && c != '\n');
    }

    buffer[strlen(buffer) - 1] = '\0'; // remove trailing \n

    (void) fclose(file);
}


int main() {

    srandom(time(NULL));

    char buffer[1024];

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        random_word("/usr/share/dict/words", buffer, sizeof(buffer));

        (void) puts(buffer);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**EXAMPLE**

```
> ./a.out
boloman
disentrance
guanase
decorable
snibbled
redemandable
Cluniac
balneal
turbidimetry
catechistically
>
```

This code doesn't need to be complex nor efficient as it's a rare event, processing-wise, that you select a new word and it happens on a human time frame, not a high speed processing one.

Comment: Wouldn't this method favor longer words? Not that that is necessarily a problem for Hangman.

Comment: I've just tried implementing this and it seems that when I run it, it returns the same word two times consecutively, then changes; rather than a different word every time.

Comment: Fixed issue - Num Gen is based on time, taking two readings in too short a timespan gives the same index.

Comment: @Lewiky, exactly right.  It's just a seed issue.  If your program asked for ten random words in a row, it'd work fine.  But if you invoke my example too quickly, it reseeds with the same time and produces the same word.  Just an artifact of the example, not a real problem.

Comment: @DavidBowling, can you explain that bias?  It seems to me it has a greater chance of randomly landing in the middle of a long word (which it ignores and moves past) and then returns the following word.  Are you saying long words are more likely to follow long words than are short words?

Comment: You are correct. I meant that it would favor words following long words.

Answer (score 1):

The easy way is to put in in an array, then get a random index.
The more complex, but efficient, is to read an index of each word, save to another file, and then, just read the sector where that word is stored.
Really, just put it in an array.